# Allow to open website on webview only

Tags: android, html, security, webview

I want to ask about the security of web application.

I'm developing on web site for an inventory management system by web service.
And wrapping as android application with the webview.

But my client ask **the website can be opened in android application only**.

I think it is possible with **agent header** when web server response to request.
But it just a makeshift.

So is there any way to check the website is opened in browser not authorized application?

I used spring boot for web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Once you expose an endpoint publicly, you can always try to connect to it with whatever software supporting the protocol (or an analyzer which will reverse-engineer the protocol).

This said, you can make it difficult by obfuscation.

One solution is to use **information provided by the client** (browser in your case). This is usually the agent header (as you mention) but can also be some fingerprinting. You could for instance detect the size of the screen and make some decisions from there on.

Another solution is to use some **secrets** (better call them "secrets") to show the backend application (or API) that some specific code is calling. I can imagine that you could bundle the HTML/JS/CSS code in your application, together with a key so only the application owners will be able to send a recognizable traffic (recognized by the backednd).

All of this is more or less difficult to crack but with some layers you will get rid of at least some population which would like to access the site via other means than an app.

Comment: you could always try using userAgent detection. Redirect if it is not an in your list of acceptable user agents. but this is not a super effective option as  a savvy user can set their user agent to whatever they wish.